# C++ to java, language equivalency questions

Tags: java, c++

I've grown quite fond of some structures in C++, and I've recently been porting over some old school projects to java, but have run into a few snags that weren't resolved by simple google searches... So I figured that I'd ask here:

In C++ I'm quite fond of `Stringstream`, `vector`, `list`, and `dequeue`,  but haven't been able to find adequate documentation on any of them.   When I try to use `Vector`, netbeans tells me that it's deprecated, does that mean some other code took it's place?  Is there some other container I should be using instead?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For `Stringstream` you can use `java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream`

C++'s `Vector<T>` is basically the same as `java.util.ArrayList<T>`

The closest match for `list<T>` would be `java.util.LinkedList<T>` -- both are implemented as doubly linked lists (though if all you want is an ordered collection of elements you should probably use the more generic interface, `java.lang.List<T>`)

You can also use `java.util.LinkedList<T>` for your implementation of `deque<T>`.  `java.util.LinkedList<T>` implements all the functions necessary for a queue/stack.

The reason NetBeans is telling you `Vector<T>` is deprecated is because it is usually a better idea to use the data structures introduced by the Java Collections API.  In the place of `Vector<T>` place, you should be using things like `java.util.ArrayList<T>` or `java.util.LinkedList<T>`.

Comment: +1 for mentioning java.lang.List<T>.  It's worth understanding how in Java you can define a variable generically (List<T>) and then instantiate it with your preferred implementation (LinkedList<T>, ArrayList<T>)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, I suppose I'll go give LinkedList a spin!

Answer (score 1):

For vector, list and dequeue and other Collections take a look at this http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html

You may also find those classes interesting: InputStream, OutputStream, BufferedReader, BufferedWriter and StringBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong, Vector is even slower than ArrayList because it is synchronized.

Comment: You are not wrong. Also, the synchronisation is naive so it's not actually that useful. That's why you should always use the newer synchronisation APIs like `Collections.synchronizedList()` or `CopyOnWriteArrayList` etc.